# Spring Web Flow PathVariable

Tags: spring-webflow, path-variables

This question is of two parts

- Is it possible to provide Path Variables for Spring Web Flow?
- Is it possible to hide the execution key in the URL

The current URL is as follows: `http://localhost/bugs/ticket/?execution=e2s1`

Here, the associated Web Flow location pattern is 
`<flow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/flow.xml" />`
where the Folder Structure is: `bugs/ticket/flow.xml`

Is it possible to provide the ticket ID in the URL itself and point to the appropriate flow - i.e. the URL should be `http://localhost/bugs/ticket/102?execution=e2s1`, but still the flow is taken from `bugs/ticket/flow.xml`

I tried with the following patterns - `value="/**/*/flow.xml"`, `flow-path id="bugs/ticket/*"` etc, but to no avail.

Also, is it possible to hide the execution key also in the URL? Is it possible to send it via say HTTP header which can be pulled in at Spring Web Flow ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer all your questions

This is how I send parameters into the flow

**External Page**

```
<a href="<c:url value='/flowpage?uid=${variable1.field}'/>">Enter Flow</a>
```

**Flow**

```
<view-state>
   <on-entry>
     <set name="variable2.field" value="requestParameters.uid"/>
   </on-entry>
</view-state>
```